# how macros in document files works?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm analyzing malicious document and started locking in Process monitor. I see lots of windows events working in background. can someone explain how macros process

Comment: no one can tell you what the code does without seeing the code. Please see [ask].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.